# CardView doesn't support TransitionDrawable?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-cardview, transitiondrawable

I tried to animate a switch-color  on `CardView` background, but I'm getting this:

> Cannot resolve method 'setCardBackgroundColor(android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable)'

If `CardView` does not support `TransitionDrawable`, then how can we achieve something like this?

```
public void setCardBackground(CardView cardView) {
    ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE), new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)};
    TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
     //cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(trans);
    trans.startTransition(5000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [`View#setBackground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))?

```
public void setCardBackground(CardView cardView) {
    ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE), new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)};
    TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
        cardView.setBackground(trans);
    } else {
        cardView.setBackgroundDrawable(trans);
    }
    trans.startTransition(5000);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. It breaks rounded corners on the CardView.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by azizbekian will break rounded corners of the CardView. To set the background color of one, you should use the CardView-specific method `setCardBackgroundColor`.

Here is a solution that preserves them:

**Kotlin**

```
fun setCardBackground(cardView: CardView) {
    val colors = intArrayOf(Color.BLACK, Color.RED)
    ValueAnimator.ofArgb(*colors).apply {
        duration = 5000
        addUpdateListener {
            cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(it.animatedValue as Int)
        }
        start()
    }
}
```

**Java**

```
public void setCardBackground(CardView cardView) {
    int[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.RED};
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(colors);
    animator.setDuration(5000);
    animator.addUpdateListener(animation ->
            cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(((int) animator.getAnimatedValue()))
    );
    animator.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nohus, exactly what I needed!